# how to show data in datalist from database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have three tables 1)Manager, 2)Teamleader, 3)Agent.
i want to show how many agent are in particular manager, like i have shown in image, natasha,odeya are in under ben and Emma is under Jonny but both are under john. i want to show these agents list in datalist

[image]

i use this code:

```
string agent = Session["UserEmail"].ToString();
ArrayList Course = new ArrayList();
string query = "select Email_ID from tblTeamLeaders where IsActive_By='" + agent + "'";
using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Course.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }
    conn.Close();
}
foreach (string value in Course)
{
    conn.Open();
    string str = "select DISTINCT name from [tblAgents] where IsActive='True' and IsActive_By='" + value + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    DataList1.DataSource = ds;
    DataList1.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You need read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code here is a textbook example of the sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: You might also take a look at this article. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ You can do this with a single query instead of queries over and over in a loop.